# Given an SPD matrix, any diagonal submatrix of full rank must be SPD.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I need help with the following proof:

Given a symmetric positive-definite matrix, show that any diagonal submatrix of full rank must also be symmetric positive-definite.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then the upper left $k\times k$ submatrix of $A$ is $M^T A M$ for some $n\times k$ matrix $M$ (*what is the matrix $M$*?).

Answer (score 0):

An $n \times n$ matrix $Q$ is SPD if $x^T Q x> 0$ for every vector $x$. This is also true the vector $x$ contains zeros.

Let now $P= Q_{i:j,i:j}$ some submatrix around the matrix diagonal with $i<j<n $. Then we have $y^T P y = x^T Q x > 0$ where $x$ contains the the vector $y$ and $x_k = 0$ for $k<i$ and $k>j$.